# JEP parsing with placeholders

Tags: java, parsing, expression

I need to make use of [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) library for parsing some expressions in java.
I am facing issues with placeholders.

After a call to the database, a value is  returned which needs to be transformed,
For eg: if a value = 50 is returned , it needs to be transformed to a new value = {{value}}/10( format is exactly how it is in the database)

To do so, I tried replicating some scenarios:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JEP j = new JEP();    
    try {
     j.addVariable("x", 9);
     j.parseExpression("x/5");
     
     Object a=j.getValueAsObject();
     System.out.println(a);
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

```
The answer is 1.8 (Expected)
```

Now, to replicate the real scenario, if i do the below, the code fails

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
try {

    JEP j = new JEP();  
     j.addVariable("{x}", 9);
     j.parseExpression("{x}/5");
     
     Object a=j.getValueAsObject();
     System.out.println(a);
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I expect a 1.8 here, but it returns a null.. Could anyone please suggest or provide some inputs here?

Comment: You are using "{x}" , but in their example it is just x

Comment: yes I am trying to replicate the scenario what I see from the database.. is there anything additional that needs to be done here?

Comment: Obviously curly braces are not accepted in variable names.

Comment: Any suggestions on how do i need to parse them, considering the placeholders?

Comment: Eliminate the curly braces and apply parsing?

Comment: Maybe replace curly braces with underscores? Or just remove them if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `{}` are not supported, however `()` are supported.  Therefore I recommend that you do a String manipulation of `{}` and replace with `()` when possible.

An example below:

```
JEP jepExpression = new JEP();
jepExpression.setAllowUndeclared(true);
jepExpression.addStandardConstants();
jepExpression.addStandardFunctions();

jepExpression.parseExpression("(a + 1) * (b - 3)");
jepExpression.addVariable("a", 1);
jepExpression.addVariable("b", 2);

System.out.println("Value: " + jepExpression.getValueAsObject());

Value: -2.0
```